# How to Get Monthly/Quarterly Sales Percent

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I Have a table of Monthly Sales

```
Quarter Month Monthly Sales
1       Jan   586
1       Feb   204
1       Mar   465
2       Apr   684
2       May   756
2       Jun   97
```

Now I want a result a below

```
Quarter Month Monthly Sales Total Sales% Quarterly Sales%
1       Jan    586           20.98%         45.25%
1       Feb    204           7.30%          16.25%
1       Mar    465           16.65%         37.05%
2       Apr    684           24.49%         44.50%
2       May    756           27.07%         49.18%
2       Jun    97            3.47           6.31%
```

Total Sales% = Monthly Sales/Sum (Monthly Sales)
Quarterly Sales% = Monthly Sales/ Quarterly Sales

How Do i Get this output in SQL?

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Using `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT 
    s.*,
    [Total Sales %] = CAST(CAST(s.MonthlySales/t.Total * 100.00 AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS VARCHAR(5)) +'%',
    [Quarterly Sales %] = CAST(CAST(s.MonthlySales/q.QtrTotal* 100.00 AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS VARCHAR(5)) +'%'
FROM Sales s
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT Total = SUM(MonthlySales) * 1.0
    FROM Sales
) t
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT QtrTotal = SUM(MonthlySales) * 1.0
    FROM Sales
    WHERE Quarter = s.Quarter
    GROUP BY Quarter
)q
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle you should be using the `ratio_to_report` analytic function. (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions124.htm)

```
select quarter,
       month,
       monthly_sales,
       round(ratio_to_report(monthly_sales) over() * 100, 2) as total_sales_pct,
       round(ratio_to_report(monthly_sales) over(partition by quarter) * 100, 2) as qtr_sales_pct
  from monthly_sales;
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71aeb7/1/0

The above assumes you're selecting data for just one year as the analytic function will interpret the given result set. If your query spans multiple years you need to additionally partition by whatever column represents the year in your real table.